# Javascript hook when Stripe payment info is entered

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce, stripe-payments, hook

I've got a Woocommerce site (Wordpress). Is there a way to fire a JavaScript event when the payment info (Stripe) is entered by the user?

Comment: Download the stripe plugin you're using, open the plugin files in your IDE or code Editor then search inside all the JS for `.trigger(` keyword. then you can find the trigger event name from the search results that you can use.

Comment: I think this resource might be helpful, https://newdevzone.com/posts/list-of-all-js-events-in-woocommerce.

Comment: @pgs, can you please tell how this blog will help for stripe webhooks?